# Override protected methods called from private method of parent

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

I have a class that runs tons of logic and exposes `protected` methods to allow inheriting classes to change the regular flow.
I'm using Spring Framework to define my components.

Here's a code example of the Parent class exposing a methods called `influence` that I can override in the Child class:

```
@Component
public class Parent {
   public void someLogic(...) {
      ...
      do();
   }

   private void do(...) {
      this.influence(...);
      ...
   }

   protected void influence(...) {
      ... // regular flow
   }
}
```

```
@Component
public class Child extends Parent {

   @Override
   protected void influence(...) {
      ... // MY FLOW
   }
}
```

When running the code, I see that my class isn't being called even though it's being initialised.
I narrowed it down to the protected method not being called when accessed from a private method but I couldn't find any explanation of this online.

Why is my code not being called?
How can I overpass this obstacle?

Comment: Likely that the object on which the method is being called is not a `Child` instance. You probably need to check how your objects are being created. I'm also curious to know how you managed to create a method called `do`...

Comment: Extending on what @ernest_k said: Why are both `Parent` and `Child` components? How are they included (autowired)?